# Should I post this question about a chemistry related joke in Louie on this site?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

This question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/162688/108725was closed but Buck Thorn, a mod, commented that maybe I should try posting it on Movies & TV, after editing it suitably.

He said,"And the TV and movie site may be open to your question if properly edited, unfortunately that may involve trial-and-error. They have chat rooms there too you may want to try."

Would that be a good idea, and how should I edit it to make it suitable?

Comment: If it's asking us to *explain* the joke I would say not.

Comment: Is there reason to believe there is meant to be any kind of chemistry joke at all in the scene? Sometimes a movie or TV has very intelligent humor in it, but most of the time, someone looked in a book until they found something that looked cool or appropriate or complicated and copied onto a prop for the shot.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I suspect there *may* be a chemistry joke in the scene only because CK's jokes have so many aspects/levels to them, so often, in my experience (just my subjective impression - OTOH he isn't known as "the king of comedy" and "the comic's comic" for nothing, I suppose). CK seems never to pass up a chance to be funny, and so he wouldn't (I speculate) choose at random the molecule being talked about by the teacher if he could add something to the scene by choosing one wisely.